# R - creating new character column based on another column

Tags: r, dataframe, character, mutate

I have reviewed [Create new character column in R data frame based on existing character vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58030173/create-new-character-column-in-r-data-frame-based-on-existing-character-vector),[How to create a data frame with numeric and character columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24901216/how-to-create-a-data-frame-with-numeric-and-character-columns),[Creating a new column of character values based on numeric value condition in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33850717/creating-a-new-column-of-character-values-based-on-numeric-value-condition-in-r), and others. From those answers, I was able to get my data frame to partially work, but I must be missing something because it's still incorrect.

Dataframe

```
assoc Transect year month SpeciesPositionGroupsize
<lgl> <fctr>   <dbl><fctr><fctr> <chr>    <dbl>
FALSE   C3  2   Jan RC  470     13
FALSE   C3  2   Jan BW  1850    3
TRUE    C3  2   Jan RC  2020    12
TRUE    C3  2   Jan BW  2020    5
FALSE   C3  2   Jan SKS 1000    4
FALSE   C3  2   Jan SKS 1310    3
```

I am trying to create a column called "habitat" based on the "position" column.

I tried

```
df.clean$habitat <- ifelse("Position">=2000, "interior",
        ifelse("Position"<2000, "edge"))
```

but all that did was create a column that listed everything as "interior".

Same with this attempt

```
df %>%
mutate(habitat = case_when("Position" > 2000 ~ "interior",
         "Position" < 2000 ~ "edge"))
```

What am I missing?

Desired output

```
assoc Transect year month SpeciesPositionGroupsize Habitat
<lgl> <fctr>   <dbl><fctr><fctr> <chr>    <dbl>    <chr>
FALSE   C3  2   Jan RC  470     13                  edge
FALSE   C3  2   Jan BW  1850    3                   edge
TRUE    C3  2   Jan RC  2020    12                  interior
TRUE    C3  2   Jan BW  2020    5                   interior
FALSE   C3  2   Jan SKS 1000    4                   edge
FALSE   C3  2   Jan SKS 1310    3                   edge
```

Dput data

```
structure(list(assoc = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE
), Transect = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("C3", 
"Msolwa", "Mwani", "Sanje"), class = "factor"), year = c(2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2), month = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("Jan", 
"Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", 
"Nov", "Dec"), class = "factor"), Species = structure(c(4L, 2L, 
4L, 2L, 6L, 6L), levels = c("BABO", "BW", "Mang", "RC", "RD", 
"SKS"), class = "factor"), Position = c("470", "1850", "2020", 
"2020", "1000", "1310"), Groupsize = c(13, 3, 12, 5, 4, 3)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Your `Position` column is `character` class but you are expecting it to behave as a numeric. It seems like it should be numeric. (`<` and `>=` on character columns will use alphabetical order, meaning `"2" > "100000"` is TRUE.) Convert it with `df.clean$Position <- as.numeric(df.clean$Position)`

Comment: Even when I convert, I still get the same issue.

Comment: Also, when you refer to a column, don't quote it (unless you're using `[[`). `"Position"` isn't the position column, it's just a string. The column is `df.clean$Position` or `df.clean[["Position"]]`, or inside `mutate()` and other `dplyr` functions just `Position` without quotes.

Comment: If you convert it to numeric, then any of these should work: `df.clean$habitat <- ifelse(df.clean$Position >=2000, "interior", "edge")` or `df.clean <- df.clean %>% mutate(habitat = case_when(Position > 2000 ~ "interior", "Position" < 2000 ~ "edge"))`

Comment: Thank you, the first one worked. And thank you for correcting me on my code in general.